# "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" from an array initialized with a length of zero/empty but it's definitely not empty when requested

Tags: arrays, swift, tableview, uistepper, indexpath

So I currently have a tableView in a ViewController called `GearComponentViewController` that has custom tableViewCells that have a UIStepper in them to control a quantity label and conforms to the custom protocol `Stepper`.

```
protocol Stepper {
func stepperWasPressed(didIncrease: Bool, namePassed: String, userindexPath: Int)
}
```

And here's the code for the `GearComponentTableViewCell`:

```
class GearComponentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var mainVC = GearComponentViewController()
var tableViewCellPosition: Int! = nil

// Image
@IBOutlet weak var itemImage: UIImageView!

// Name
@IBOutlet weak var itemName: UILabel!

// Weight
@IBOutlet weak var itemWeight1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemWeight2: UILabel!

// Quanity
@IBOutlet weak var itemQuanity: UILabel!
@IBAction func stepperPressed (_ sender: UIStepper!){
    if (sender.value == 1) {
        print("up and item: \(itemName.text!)");
        sender.value = 0
        mainVC.stepperWasPressed(didIncrease: true, namePassed: itemName.text!, userindexPath: tableViewCellPosition)
    } else if (sender.value == -1) {
        print("down and item: \(itemName.text!)");
        sender.value = 0
        mainVC.stepperWasPressed(didIncrease: false, namePassed: itemName.text!, userindexPath: tableViewCellPosition)
    }
}

// Notes
@IBOutlet weak var itemNotes: UILabel!
```

}

It detects if the user clicked on the plus button or the minus button on the stepper and calls the function from the protocol `stepperWasPressed()`

Finally here's the code for the `mainVC` referenced:

```
extension GearComponentViewController: Stepper {
    
    func refreshTableViewCell() {
        print("arrayPosition: \(arrayPosition)")
//        gearTableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    
    
    func stepperWasPressed(didIncrease: Bool, namePassed: String, userindexPath: Int) {
        
        if didIncrease {
            arrayPosition = userindexPath
            print("arrayPosition: \(arrayPosition)")
//            itemArray[userindexPath].quanity += 1
            print("userindexPath: \(userindexPath) -- namePassed: \(namePassed) -- didIncrease: \(didIncrease)")
            print("increase selected")
            refreshTableViewCell()
        }else {
            arrayPosition = userindexPath
            print("arrayPosition: \(arrayPosition)")
//            itemArray[userindexPath].quanity -= 1
            print("userindexPath: \(userindexPath) -- namePassed: \(namePassed) -- didIncrease: \(didIncrease)")
            print("decrease selected")
            refreshTableViewCell()
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to do either `itemArray[userindexPath].quanity += 1` or `itemArray[userindexPath].quanity -= 1` I'm getting the error listed in the title, but to be even able to call that part of the function the count of my itemArray has to be greater than zero/empty because I'm being presented a cell with a stepper in it.

Full GearComponentViewController:

```
import UIKit

class GearComponentViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    var arrayPosition: Int = 0
    
    // Data Sources
    var itemArray: [GearItem] = []
    var totalWeight1: Int = 0
    var totalWeight2: Int = 0
    var totalItems: Int = 0
    
    // Weight Label Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var weight1LabelOutlet: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weight2LabelOutlet: UILabel!
    
    // Item Count Label Outlet
    
    @IBOutlet weak var totalCountLabelOutlet: UILabel!
    
    // TableView Outlet
    @IBOutlet weak var gearTableView: UITableView!
    
    // Bar Button Item
    @IBAction func addItemPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        presentAlert()
    }
    
    // View Did Load
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        gearTableView.dataSource = self
        gearTableView.delegate = self
        print("Gear Component View Controller successfully loaded.")
        
        updateUI()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    //MARK: - UI Updater
    func updateUI() {
        addTotalWeight()
        addAllItems()
    }
    
    // Adding Total Weight
    func addTotalWeight() {
        var addedWeight1: Int = 0
        var addedWeight2: Int = 0
        
        for item in itemArray {
            addedWeight1 += item.weight1 * item.quantity
            addedWeight2 += item.weight2 * item.quantity
        }
        
        totalWeight1 = addedWeight1
        totalWeight2 = addedWeight2
        
        weight1LabelOutlet.text = String("\(totalWeight1)")
        weight2LabelOutlet.text = String("\(totalWeight2)")
    }
    
    // Item Count
    func addAllItems() {
        var addedValue: Int = 0
        
        for item in itemArray {
            addedValue += item.quantity
        }
        totalItems = addedValue
        
        totalCountLabelOutlet.text = String("\(totalItems)")
        print("Total items: \(totalItems)")
    }
    
   
    
    
    //MARK: - Alert
    func presentAlert() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add Item", message: "Enter item info here", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        // AlertController Textfields
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Name"
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Weight 1"
            textField.keyboardType = .decimalPad
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Weight 2"
            textField.keyboardType = .decimalPad
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Quanity"
            textField.keyboardType = .decimalPad
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Notes"
        }
        
        // AlertController Actions
        let continueAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { [self, weak alertController] _ in
            guard let textFields = alertController?.textFields else { return }
            
            if let userItemName = textFields[0].text,
               let userItemWeight1 = textFields[1].text,
               let userItemWeight2 = textFields[2].text,
               let userItemQuanity = textFields[3].text,
               let userItemNotes = textFields[4].text {
                
                print("Name: \(userItemName)")
                print("Item Weight 1: \(userItemWeight1)")
                print("Item Weight 2: \(userItemWeight2)")
                print("Item Quantity: \(userItemQuanity)")
                print("Item Notes: \(userItemNotes)")
                
                let userSubmittedItem = GearItem(itemName: userItemName, itemImage: UIImage(systemName: "photo.on.rectangle.angled")!, itemWeight1: Int(userItemWeight1) ?? 0, itemWeight2: Int(userItemWeight2) ?? 0, itemQuantity: Int(userItemQuanity) ?? 1, itemNotes: userItemNotes ?? "", creationPosition: itemArray.count + 1)
                
                self.itemArray.append(userSubmittedItem)
                gearTableView.reloadData()
                updateUI()
            }
        }
        
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)
        cancelAction.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "titleTextColor")
        
        alertController.addAction(continueAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        
        self.present(alertController,
                     animated: true)
    }
    
    //MARK: - TableView Protocol Functions
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = gearTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! GearComponentTableViewCell
        cell.itemName.text = itemArray[indexPath.row].name
        cell.itemImage.image = itemArray[indexPath.row].image
        cell.itemWeight1.text = String("\(itemArray[indexPath.row].weight1)")
        cell.itemWeight2.text = String("\(itemArray[indexPath.row].weight2)")
        cell.itemQuanity.text = String("\(itemArray[indexPath.row].quantity)")
        cell.itemNotes.text = itemArray[indexPath.row].notes
        
        cell.tableViewCellPosition = indexPath.row
        
        return cell
    }
    
    //MARK: - Swipeable TableViewCell
    private func deleteItem(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {
        itemArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        gearTableView.reloadData()
        updateUI()
        print("Item Deleted")
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { [weak self] (action, view, completionHandler) in
            self?.deleteItem(indexPath)
            completionHandler(true)
        }
        action.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
        
    }
}

extension GearComponentViewController: Stepper {
    
    func refreshTableViewCell() {
        print("arrayPosition: \(arrayPosition)")
//        itemArray[arrayPosition].quantity += 1
//        gearTableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    
    
    func stepperWasPressed(didIncrease: Bool, namePassed: String, userindexPath: Int) {
        
        if didIncrease {
            arrayPosition = userindexPath
            print("arrayPosition: \(arrayPosition)")
//            itemArray[userindexPath].quanity += 1
            print("userindexPath: \(userindexPath) -- namePassed: \(namePassed) -- didIncrease: \(didIncrease)")
            print("increase selected")
            refreshTableViewCell()
        }else {
            arrayPosition = userindexPath
            print("arrayPosition: \(arrayPosition)")
//            itemArray[userindexPath].quanity -= 1
            print("userindexPath: \(userindexPath) -- namePassed: \(namePassed) -- didIncrease: \(didIncrease)")
            print("decrease selected")
            refreshTableViewCell()
        }
    }
}
```

[And here's an image of what my app looks like right now for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiNW6.png)

Comment: You probably don't want to _create_ a GearComponentViewController (`var mainVC`) in your GearComponentTableViewCell. What you really should have in your cell is a _closure_ variable which handles the users actions. This closure should be initialised in `tableView(_: cellForRowAt:)` and calls into the table view controller. Ensure you do not introduce reference cycles.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your delegate function. You try to delegate on a new instance of your GearComponentViewController(). Try replacing the
`var mainVC = GearComponentViewController()` in your custom cell Class with

```
var delegate:Stepper?
```

and call the delegate with

```
delegate?.stepperWasPressed(didIncrease:...
```

also don't forget to register your delegate on your GearComponentViewController() in the cellForRow function like

```
cell.delegate = self
```

Comment: One thing I would add is that your cells should never keep track of their indexPath. What happens if you insert or delete a cell? All of the indexPath's tracked by every other cell becomes invalid. If you are going to use a delegate, pass the cell object. That way you can call `tableView.indexPath(for: cell)` to get the latest indexPath for a cell. Remember, indexPaths and cell objects don't remain paired.